# Finding the orientation of lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, orientation

I want to know the dominant orientation of the green lines in the purple box because I want to place a grid perpendicular to these lines.

[image: map]

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the  [`main_angle()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#main-angle) function:

> Returns the angle of the long axis (clockwise, in degrees from North)
> of the oriented minimal bounding rectangle, which completely covers
> the geometry.